# Hiding column using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, column, qgis-custom-widgets

How can I hide a column in QGIS 3 using PyQGIS:

In QGIS 2 it was quite simple:

```py
editFormConf = layer.editFormConfig()
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(columnName)
editFormConf.setWidgetType(idx, "Hidden")
```

I investigated, and now in QGIS 3 it has changed to something like

```py
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(columnName)
editor_widget_setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup(...)
layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(idx, editor_widget_setup)
```

The problem is the use of the constructor `QgsEditorWidgetSetup(...)`

How to tell the constructor that this field is hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QGIS 3 is necessary to use [`QgsEditorWidgetSetup`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsEditorWidgetSetup.html) in order to define the widget type and configuration for the field.

The following is minimal working example in Python Console which set a widget of type 'TextEdit' with MultiLine property set to True:

```py
vl = iface.activeLayer()
idx = vl.fields().indexFromName('field')

setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('TextEdit', {'IsMultiline': 'True'})
vl.setEditorWidgetSetup(idx, setup)
```

So, to hide your column it is enough to do:

```py
setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('Hidden', {})
vl.setEditorWidgetSetup(idx, setup)
```